5.x - Matrix Frontend Form Submissions
Has anyone found a way to create matrix field submissions with a frontend form?
The docs for 5.x mention this section hasn't been updated and that the functionality has changed drastically.
Craft 5.x - Saving Matrix Fields
I'm trying to store user social media profiles (title and url fields) but can't find a way to save them upon registration. I have even tried setting the min/max to  5 so I know how many there will be. Each new user has 5 fields available in their profile via the CP, but they do not show up on the front end, my query returns no results.
With the code below, I am able to display existing matrix content, once either field contains data.
{% set userSocialProfiles = user.socialMediaProfiles %}

{% set profileCount = userSocialProfiles|length %}

{% if userSocialProfiles|length > 0 %}
    {% set socialCount = 0 %}
    <div class="relative formGroup">
        <label for="SocialMediaProfiles" class="formLabel w-full">
            <strong>Social Media Profiles</strong>
        </label>
        <div class="relative formGroupSplit flex-wrap">

            {% for  profile in  userSocialProfiles %}
                {% set socialCount = socialCount+1 %}
                <div id="social_Profile_{{socialCount}}" class="relative formGroupMulti">
                    <label for="socialProfile-{{socialCount}}" class="formLabel text-sm">Profile
                        {{socialCount}}
                        of
                        {{profileCount}}</label>
                    <div class="relative formGroup w-full gap-2">
                        {% set profileTitle = 'fields[socialMediaProfiles][entries][uid:' ~ (profile.uid) ~ '][fields][altTitle]' %}
                        {{ input('text', profileTitle, profile.title ? null, {
                            id: profileTitle,
                            name: profileTitle,
                            class: 'formInputText ' ~ (user ? user.hasErrors('profileTitle') ? ' formInputError' : ''),
                            autocomplete: profileTitle ? null,
                        }) }}
                        {{ _self.errorList(user.getErrors(profileTitle)) }}
                        
                        {% set profileUrl = 'fields[socialMediaProfiles][entries][uid:' ~ (profile.uid) ~ '][fields][offSiteUrl]' %}
                        {{ input('url', profileUrl, profile.offSiteUrl, {
                            id: profileUrl,
                            class: 'formInputText ' ~ (user ? user.hasErrors('profileUrl') ? ' formInputError' : ''),
                            autocomplete: profileUrl,
                        }) }}
                        {{ _self.errorList(user.getErrors(profileUrl)) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

These users will not have access to the CP so I need to find a way to display the phantom fields visible in the CP, via the frontend.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!
